# How do I use VBA to change a PowerPoint's embedded chart links?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint template full of embedded charts, and I would like to use VBA to change the charts' links from a template excel file to a client's excel file. I'm running the VBA script from the client's excel file (with the PowerPoint reference library enabled).

In the script I attempt to reassign each PowerPoint chart's Chart.ChartData.Workbook property to the client's workbook.

```
pptShape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook = ThisWorkbook
```

No error message comes up when I run it, but when I click file->info->edit links, none of the chart links have been changed. How can I resolve this, or what can I do instead? Please don't suggest changing the charts to something other than embedded charts; I have to keep them as embedded charts.

Answer (score 0):

Charts are either embedded or linked. Assuming they are linked, the statement needs to look more like this:

```
pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = Replace(LCase _
(pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName), LCase(oldFilePath), newFilePath)
```

Taken from this page that's a whole article on this subject: [Edit links in PowerPoint using VBA](https://exceloffthegrid.com/edit-links-in-powerpoint-using-vba/). And here's the MS reference page: [LinkFormat.SourceFullName property (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.linkformat.sourcefullname)